ASP.NET Core SignalR Dependency Injection in OnConnectedAsync
I have created a service like so: builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISessionManagerService, SessionManagerService>(); and can create new methods in my Hub with it as a parameter, like so:
public async Task Send(string action, object args, ISessionManagerService sessionManager)
{
    await Clients.All.Receive(action, args);
}

However, when I override OnConnectedAsync, I cannot add an ISessionManagerService as a parameter. I have tried OnConnectedAsync(ISessionManagerService sessionManager) and OnConnectedAsync([FromServices] ISessionManagerService sessionManager), neither of which works (the error is "no suitable method found to override").
What is the proper way to access my service in the OnConnectedAsync method?

DI for OnConnectedAsync can be done in the Hub constructor. For example:
private ISessionManagerService sessionManager;

public MiddlewareHub(ISessionManagerService sessionManager)
{
    this.sessionManager = sessionManager;
}

While this method works, it's not as clean and easy as what can be done for new methods in the Hub. If anyone has a better method, please share it.
